# Excel Marker Line Graph Coloring Issue

Tags: vba, excel

I have been working on a macro for the past week to automatically create charts in excel. I have gotten pretty far along with it (thanks in large part to help from this website and its users), but I am stuck on a seemingly insignificant step. For some reason my line with markers graph shows up with discolorations in it. What I mean by this is that the middle fill of the marker is the standard blue that excel defaults to. I think the issue lies with the [ .Visible = msoTrue] line but no matter how I manipulate the code, I cannot make my markers one solid color.

The code is below

```
Sub DM1R_Graph()

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In Sheets
        ws.Activate

If ws.Name <> "WSNs" Then

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim xVals As Range, yVals As Range
Dim co As Shape, cht As Chart, s As Series

    Set sht = ActiveSheet
    Set co = sht.Shapes.AddChart()
    Set cht = co.Chart

    'remove any existing series
    Do While cht.SeriesCollection.Count > 0
        cht.SeriesCollection(1).Delete
    Loop

      cht.ChartType = xlLineMarkers

    'get the extent of the XValues...
    'below is the first Y axis entry (Oil)
    '(change the 2nd offset number to get what you want)

    Set xVals = sht.Range(sht.Range("B2"), sht.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
    Set yVals = xVals.Offset(0, 2)



    Set s = cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    s.XValues = xVals
    s.Values = yVals


    With s.Format.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 176, 80)
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With
    With s.Format.Line
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 176, 80)
        .Transparency = 0
    End With

    'below is the second y axis entry (Gas)

    Set xVals = sht.Range(sht.Range("B2"), sht.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
    Set yVals = xVals.Offset(0, 4)



    Set s = cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    s.XValues = xVals
    s.Values = yVals


    With s.Format.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With
    With s.Format.Line
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        .Transparency = 0
    End With


    'below is the third y axis entry (water)

    Set xVals = sht.Range(sht.Range("B2"), sht.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
    Set yVals = xVals.Offset(0, 5)



    Set s = cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    s.XValues = xVals
    s.Values = yVals


    With s.Format.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 176, 240)
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With
    With s.Format.Line
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 176, 240)
        .Transparency = 0
    End With

    'end Y axis entries



    cht.HasLegend = True

  'below applies the legend names to be whatever are in parenthesis'

    cht.Legend.Select
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "Oil (BO)"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Name = "Gas (MCF)"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).Name = "Water (BW)"




'below applies the data labels

cht.SeriesCollection(1).Select
    cht.SeriesCollection(1).ApplyDataLabels


cht.SeriesCollection(2).Select
    cht.SeriesCollection(2).ApplyDataLabels


cht.SeriesCollection(3).Select
    cht.SeriesCollection(3).ApplyDataLabels



'below orients the datalabels to either above,below,right,or left

cht.SeriesCollection(1).Select
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.Select
    Selection.Position = xlLabelPositionRight

cht.SeriesCollection(2).Select
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).DataLabels.Select
    Selection.Position = xlLabelPositionAbove

cht.SeriesCollection(3).Select
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).DataLabels.Select
    Selection.Position = xlLabelPositionLeft


   'below moves the chart

   Dim iChart As Long
  Dim lTop As Double

  lTop = ActiveSheet.Range("Q10").Top
  For iChart = 1 To ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Count
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(iChart).Top = lTop
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(iChart).Left = ActiveSheet.Range("Q1").Left
    lTop = lTop + ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(iChart).Height + ActiveSheet.Range("5:7").Height
  Next






'below deals with the chart title

    cht.SetElement (msoElementChartTitleAboveChart)
    With cht.ChartTitle
        .Text = sht.Name & Chr(10) & "Oil,Gas, and Water Production Through Well Life "
        .Characters.Font.Size = 12
    End With

'below adds a filter to one column. You cannot have more than 1 filter per sheet.

Columns("L:L").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter




End If

    Next ws



End Sub
```

Below is a picture showing what I mean. You can see it obviously in the red series, but it also appears in the green and blue series as well.

[image: bad fill on graphs]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to set the `MarkerBackgroundColor` on the series.

```
s.MarkerBackgroundColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I am new to coding and have spent hours spinning my wheel on this small problem.